# application insights traces query doesn't work from azure cli command

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, appinsights

I would like to execute my application insights traces from my vscode's `azure cli` command.
I could get all details with the below command.
`az monitor app-insights query --app myappinsight1 --analytics-query traces --resource-group myRG` 
But I need more granular filters like dump only logs of last 10 minutes.
Using `traces | where timestamp > ago(10min)` in `Azure portal appinsights` query editor works fine, but gives error with `azure cli` command.
Here is my query `az monitor app-insights query --app myappinsight1 --analytics-query traces | where timestamp > ago(10min) --resource-group myRG`
I tried making quotes or escaping around symbols but didn't work.
Can anybody please help what wrong I am doing in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Looks in case of make granular filters on the query, we need to quote with `"` for the query.
In my case quote for `traces` command is  `"traces | where timestamp > ago(10min)"`.
 Complete CLI command with which I can get the logs:
`az monitor app-insights query --app myappinsight1 --analytics-query "traces | where timestamp > ago(10min)" --resource-group myRG`